# Display inline-block not working, 2nd div appears beneath, and on inspect element appears as display: block

Tags: html, css, block

REALLY struggling with this code, it is the CSS I'm struggling with beforehand I was floating the divs left and right, but a web designer at work told me to use inline-blocks instead and %'s for height and width as before i was using pixels... there is something wrong with my "main" div it will not align horizontally when I used the inspect element function in chrome it is saying that it is a block element and not an inline block element nothing I do seems to change this!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Chillblast </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="container">
                    <div id="header">
                                                    <!-- <img src="img.jpg" width="800" height="200" alt="logo" /> setting 
                                                                image as header -->
                    <h1> <u>Lorem Ipsum</u></h1>
                    <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    var myvar = "Welcome";
                    alert(myvar);
                    </script>
                    </div> 

                <div id="content">
                    <div id="navi">
                        <h3> <u>Navigation</u></h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Home</a></li> <!-- creating a css class   
                                                                    called selected as this is
                                                                     the page we are on -->
                            <li><a href="form.html"> Quote me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html"> Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Contact us</a></li>
                    </div>

                    <div id="main">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec condimentum urna nec nibh varius aliquam.<br>
                        Pellentesque sit amet justo lectus. Sed vehicula purus in porta fermentum. Integer malesuada non augue id sollicitudin.<br>
                        Curabitur non purus elementum, porttitor nisl nec, vestibulum mauris. Ut euismod urna tortor.<br>
                        Curabitur consequat mi eu sapien laoreet, vitae pharetra magna porttitor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et<br>
                        magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam et placerat massa. Fusce felis tellus, <br>
                        gravida at convallis vitae, vestibulum eu sapien. Suspendisse sed sapien egestas, scelerisque risus ut,<br>
                        molestie dui. Etiam lacinia tellus a aliquet faucibus. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>      
                <div id="footer">
                Footer Copyright &copy; Andrew doyle
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>


My CSS is as follows:


    body{
                          /* dont need to call id*/
        background-color:black;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        font-family: lobster, baskerville, sans-serif, arial;     /* set the font for the whole body,
                                                       use back up fonts too*/
    }

    a{                                                  /*In the same way we targeted the body tag we can target the a tag*/
        text-decoration: none;                          /* links not underlined*/
            color: white;                                   /* links are coloured red*/


    }

    p{

        color:#FFFFFF;
    }

    #container{

        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-image:url("spc.png"); 


    }

    h1{ /* using commas i could set it for h1,h2,h3*/
        margin:0; /* gets rid of margin*/
    }

    #header {
        width:100%;
        height:10%;
        background:transparent;                              /* background of div id set to blue */                                 /* text set to red*/
        text-align: center;                                 /* aligns text in the header to middle of page*/
        padding: 20px;
        color: white;
    }

                                                            /* #content{ padding-left:10px and all seperate directions or can use 
                                                                padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px
                                                                1st is top 2nd is right 3rd is bottom and 4th is the left and since want 
                                                                all the same we can shorten even more and just put 10px*/

    #content {

        width: 100%;
        height: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }





    #navi{
        display: inline-block;
        width:20%;
        height:70%;
        text-align: center;                                      /*as divs always start a new line to stop this we use float*/
        background: transparent;
        color: white;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }
    #navi ul{

        list-style-type: none;                              /* gets rid of the bullet points after targeting ul*/
                                                /*gets rid of padding */

    }




    }
    #main{ 

        display: inline-block;
        width: 80%;
        height:70%;
        background:transparent;
        margin: 0 auto; 

    }



    #main p{


    color: white; 
    }




    #footer{
        display: block;
        height: 20%;
        width: 100%;                                        /* this is to clear of all floating elements or will not appear
                                                            below, clearing both lets the div element get past all 
                                                            the floating div elements*/ 
        padding: 0px;
        background: transparent;
        color: white;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

Comment: JS FIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/andyctd/MPZKM/1/

Comment: typo: #navi ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    /* gets rid of the bullet points after targeting ul*/
    /*gets rid of padding */
}
}

2 closing brackets

http://jsfiddle.net/MPZKM/2/

Comment: what? there is 2 closing brackets

Comment: You have }} 2 closing brackets - this is mistake. There should be only one bracket.

Answer (score 0):

try  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sgcqi)

```
 #navi li {
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: sorry man, I thought you wanted to make a horizontal menu, but if you want to align the id main is prefilled #main {display:inline-block;}

Comment: as you can see in my original css I use display: inline-block;

Comment: Alex I see if I add at the bottom 

#navi li {
    display:inline-block;
}
#main {display:inline-block;
}

it works why is this? why do i have to recall main and navi div for it to work?

Comment: instead of display: inline-block; use float

Comment: I was originally using floats but a web designer at work said this way is better

Comment: need to look at the situation when to use one or the other way

Comment: why is the height of my container not filling the page? the width is but the height is only about half the page of a web browser, yet it is set to 100%

Comment: using float or what do you mean ?

Comment: i've got inline block to work now but my div container doesn't fill the web browser page the footer is in the middle of the page after that paragraph immediately after the paragraph has finished, I would like the footer at the bottom of the web browser page, i set the container heighter 100%, header 10%, navi and main 70%, footer 20% yet it seems to have taken no notice of this, the width %'s work fine

Comment: you need to press the footer to the bottom of the screen? so?

Comment: How do i press it to the bottom?

Comment: like this .wrapper {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
}


/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.header {
 height: 47px;
 background: #FFE680;
}


/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.content {
 padding: 0 0 100px;
}




/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.footer {
 width: 960px;
 margin: -100px auto 0;
 height: 100px;
 background: #BFF08E;
 position: relative;
}